# tkinter how to attach scrollbar to listbox using place?

Tags: python, tkinter

hi i want to attach scrollbar to listbox using place but it does not show up in the program
my code:

```
txt = Listbox(root, width = 60, height = 25,bd = 0, relief = SUNKEN)
lb2 = Listbox(root, width = 15, height = 25,bd=0)
txt.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.45, width = 360, height = 400, anchor=CENTER)
lb2.place(relx=0.87, rely=0.45,anchor=CENTER )

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.place(x=400,rely=0.45, width=10, height = 100, anchor = "center")
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

if i run the program, i can't see the scrollbar.

## Edited : sorry here's my full code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x600")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
#l1 = Label(root, text="Enter Message ")
l2 = Label(root, text="Enter Your Name ",font=("squarefont", 25))
ent = Entry(root, state='disabled',bd=1,borderwidth = 0,highlightthickness=0)
ent1 = Entry(root, borderwidth = 0,highlightthickness=0)
btn = Button(root, text="send",state='disabled',font=(None, 25),borderwidth = 0,highlightthickness=0)
btn1 = Button(root, text="Ok",borderwidth = 0,highlightthickness=0,font=(None, 15))

txt = Listbox(root, width = 60, height = 25,bd = 0, relief = SUNKEN)
lb2 = Listbox(root, width = 15, height = 25,bd=0)
txt.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.45, width = 360, height = 400, anchor=CENTER)
lb2.place(relx=0.87, rely=0.45,anchor=CENTER )

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.place(x=400,rely=0.45, width=10, height = 100, anchor = "center")
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

btn.place(relx = 0.87, rely =0.87, width = 90, height = 90, anchor=CENTER)
ent.place(relx=0.4, rely =0.87, width = 360, height = 90, anchor=CENTER)

btn1.place(relx =0.9, rely =0.08, anchor="center")
l2.place(relx =0.6, rely =0.08, anchor="e")
ent1.place(relx =0.6, rely =0.08, height = 30, anchor="w")

ent1.focus_set()
root.title("Messenger")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Since `frame` is never defined in your code, we can only guess why the scrollbar doesn't show up.

Comment: sorry i edited with my full code, please undownvote please

Comment: frame is defined and there's is no error when i complie this program

Comment: @Aran-Fey could you please have a look again?

Comment: The code throws a bunch of errors about `send_msg` and `send_name` not being defined, and about the file `chat.ico` not existing. Since none of these are relevant to the question, please remove the offending code.

Comment: yes because the i didn't include the code that defines send_msg function as it include socket and i have no problem with i will edit it again with code that only includes tkinter

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem, but in `root` you're mixing the `pack` layout manager with the `place` layout manager. That's never a good idea. Choose one layout manager (per widget) and stick with it.

Comment: just edited. i only want to use place() but don't i have to use pack for frame()?

Comment: i want to use place as layout manager but i don't know how to

Comment: because i need frame for scrollbar right?

Comment: At least one problem is that the scrollbar and the listbox have different parent/master. They should both be in the same parent/master.  If you're just starting out with tkinter I recommend completely avoiding `place`. It's hard to use and makes your program less responsive to changes in font sizes, screen resolutions, etc.